# Fitbit oauth2 public API stopped working. Giving error - Sorry Its not you.. Its us

Tags: ios, swift, fitbit

Few months back I prepared a demo on Fitbit oauth2 public APIs in which I used to log in with a particular user and get his activities. It was working fine. But recently, I opened the demo and tried to log in with the same user but it is not getting logged in and repeatedly giving me this error.

[image]

I tried to change the client secret key of this demo app which I registered on Fitbit but nothing happened. I am stuck here.

Comment: You are not the only person to post about this... as the error message says, it seems fitbit are having an issue on *their end* and you will need to wait for them to resolve it, we cannot do anything this end

Comment: I have found the solution to this problem on Fitbit community just now. I am posting the answer for this. Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318219/setting-up-fitbit-api-in-xcode-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with the format of **Callback URL**. I think Fitbit has recently changed it.

Earlier, the format of Callback URL was "demoapp://" but now 
it will be "demoapp://something"

Please refer to my answer on other question.

[Setting up Fitbit api in xcode Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318219/setting-up-fitbit-api-in-xcode-swift/52380947#52380947)