# iOS Fitbit Sorry… It's not you. It's us

Tags: ios, swift, fitbit

I'm using OAuth 2.0 for Fitbit integration in my iOS application. Everything is working well. But If I created new Application by

https://dev.fitbit.com/apps/new

Below is screenshot of registration new app.

[image]

Set new ClientID, ClientSecret and callbackURI but Always get below issue.

[image]

Don't know where i'm going wrong? Also try to set different type of **callback URI** like start with **https://getresponse** and etc. also try [Refer this link but did not get success.](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API-Development/Re-quot-It-s-not-you-It-s-us-quot-when-trying-to-authenticate-using-OAuth2/m-p/2868144/highlight/true#M9396)

I'm following

1) https://github.com/Stasonis/fitbit-api-example-swift
2) https://github.com/insanelydeepak/fitbit-api-example-iOS

If you want more info then pls let me know.

Comment: You are not the only person to post about this... as the error message says, it seems fitbit are having an issue on *their end* and you will need to wait for them to resolve it, we cannot do anything this end

Comment: I created second one still getting same issue ? and some App is working

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384199/fitbit-oauth2-public-api-stopped-working-giving-error-sorry-its-not-you-its?noredirect=1#comment91713674_52384199 another user has a solution from Fitbit